# WinForms: ItemCheck event triggers twice on some items

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm loading my items from a database and when they are being loaded I set a flag that stops the event from firing after the loading is done the event can and should fire. Now when I try and check off an item that wasn't checked it will change it's group accordingly, but when I remove the check mark from an item that was loaded from the db as (completed) the event will fire twice and nothing will happen:
[image]

To clarify when I check the one marked with red it works fine, but when I uncheck the one marked with yellow it doesn't work.

My code:

```
private void tasksListView_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (dontRunHandler) return;
    int itemIndex = e.Index;
    Action ChangeGroup = () =>
    {
        int projId = selectedProjectId;
        var currentItem = tasksListView.Items[itemIndex];
        tasks[projId][itemIndex].state ^= true;
        int group = (tasks[projId][itemIndex].state) ? 1 : 0; // Group 0 = Todo and Group 1 = Complete
        currentItem.Group = tasksListView.Groups[group];
    };

    tasksListView.BeginInvoke(ChangeGroup);
}
```

Comment: Pay attention to e.NewValue so these hacks are not necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant is writing: https://pastebin.com/iDikPqDW enough? Or should I still use `BeginInvoke()` as well? I've tried this code and it worked rather fine.